# Purpose of cswrapper code, sundials solver in FMPy

Tags: python, modelica, fmi, pyfmi

About FMPy which is a python package for FMU simulation. I need one clarification :
What is the purpose of cswrapper code, sundials solver or functions? Is it only required for
ModelExchange type FMU simulation and not for Co-simulation type FMU simulation?
https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the cswrapper code you can "wrap" a ME FMU as a CS FMU by adding a (sundials) solver, see https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy/issues/127. So you get from a ME a CS FMU.
Additionally, the CVODE solver can be used to simulate ME FMUs in fmpy.